# jquery parse table cell text value to date

Tags: jquery

Busy upskilling and new to jquery. I can get data from cells in an html table into a modal form that are of text format, e.g.

```
$("#modal_form_name_field").val(($(this).find("#full_name_tableId").text()));
```

How do I do this with dates? The date data in the table are of format `yyyy-mm-dd`. The format in the modal form is of DATE TYPE and formatted to `yyyy/mm/dd`. The below obviously does not work, but looking for something that would:

```
$("#DateofBirth_Modal_Form_Field").val(($(this).find("#DOB_table_row_value").text()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just want to convert the display syntax from `yyyy-mm-dd` to `yyyy/mm/dd`?  If so, try this:

```
function convertDateSyntax(dateStr){
   return dateStr.split('-').join('/');
}
    $("#DateofBirth_Modal_Form_Field").val((convertDateSyntax($(this).find("#DOB_table_row_value").text())));
```